# what is the use of finding out the radius of an atom

Tags: physical-chemistry, atomic-structure, atomic-radius, nuclear-chemistry

I happen to come across this, but what is the radius of an atom, velocity, KE, PE, etc.. actually used for?
like the formula r=0.529n^2/z and so on

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the atomic radius is a bit arbitary, you could say that it is the typical distance from the center of a nucleus to the boundary of surrounding electrons. Therefore more widely used definitions are the Van Der Waals radius, ionic radius, covalent radius etc. The notion of atomic radi as a 'length' value came about when it became possible to measure lengths using X-ray crystallography. They are normally measured in the bonded state since it is difficult to measure an isolated atom. The Radi therefore also sometimes depend on what they were bonded to during measurement too.

The atomic radius is a crude approximation, but it can give explanations and predictions of different phenomena eg. density of liquids and solids, diffusion of liquids through molecular sieves, the arrangement of atoms in crystal structures and the approximate size and shape of molecules.

The formula you refer to is the radius of the n'th Bohr orbit. Remember that the Bohr model only holds for one-electron atoms so it's applications are fairly limited. However using the Bohr model, rough energy estimations can be acheived for these atoms.

You can use calculated energy values of atoms and groups of atoms to realte back to the feasability of certain reactions occuring, products forming etc.  (from a thermodynamic approach). The Bohr model is what lead on to more compelx quantum chemical ideas and methods such as Hartree-Fock methods which allow for more accurate energy estimation of both atoms and molecules. Using this, the energies of specific orientations of molecules and atoms can be determined which can be use to estimate how likely a reaction is to proceed or what the energy of a trasnition state is!